# Expectation of a product in python sympy

Tags: python, random, sympy, expectations

In python sympy I have the following code

```
from sympy.stats import P, E, variance, covariance, Normal

mu, sigma = symbols('mu sigma')
epsilon_t = Normal('epsilon_t', 0, sigma)
epsilon_t1 = Normal('epsilon_t+1', 0, sigma)
```

which defines two (presumably independent) normal random variables. Now, I would expect that

`E(epsilon_t1*epsilon_t)`

is equal to zero, but when I run this through sympy, I get something a lot more complicated. It tells me it is zero for pi/2 > 2|larg(sigma)| and something much more complicated otherwise. I don't care about the second part, I just want it to be zero. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `help(arg)` you will get a hint that is helpful: the `arg(x)` is 0 if its `x` is positive. So if you define your parameters as positive instead of real, `arg` will be able to evaluate:

```
>>> mu, sigma = symbols('mu sigma',positive=True)
>>> epsilon_t = Normal('epsilon_t', 0, sigma)
>>> epsilon_t1 = Normal('epsilon_t+1', 0, sigma)
>>> E(epsilon_t*epsilon_t1)
0
```